# Возможна ли установка позиции ввода в UITextField по умолчанию на i позицию?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

[image]

То есть чтобы индикатор позиции ввода стоял например после +7, а не с самого начала строки. Маска номера - плэйсхолдер. И собственно говоря три вопроса:

- Возможно ли реализовать это отталкиваясь от текста плэйсхолдера?
- Возможно ли реализовать это отталкиваясь от текста UITextField?
- Возможно ли сделать невидимым сам индикатор позиции ввода?

Благодарю заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут большое поле для маневра.

Предложу пару решений, которые сразу пришли в голову:

1) Сделать два текст филда один на одном. Задний показывает плейсхолдер, передний (активный) показывает курсор. Передний короче заднего, таким образом, что курсор находится, после '+7('

2) Можно реально менять позицию курсора. Для этого использовать функцию выделения текста и передавать нулевую длину. Вот такой хелпер например:

```
+ (void)selectTextForInput:(UITextField *)input atRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *start = [input positionFromPosition:[input beginningOfDocument] 
                                             offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [input positionFromPosition:start
                                           offset:range.length];
    [input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}
```

тут надо помнить что это будет работать для текста, но не для плейсхолдера.

3) умнее всего, как мне кажется, будет вообще не использовать плейсхолдер, а сделать все текстом с аттрибутами. Для этого вместо `.text` использовать `.attributedText`. То есть сначала написать '+7( _ _ _ ) _ _ _- _ _- _ _ ' серым цветом, и считывать ввод в делегате при помощи 
`- textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` и заменять подчеркивания на то, что ввел пользователь и менять цвет на черный.

То есть когда делегат говорит, что первый символ должен поменяться, менять первое подчеркивание на тот символ и перекрашивать его (после этого возвращать `return NO;`, чтобы реально введенный пользователем символ игнорировать.)

К вопросу о том, чтобы не убрать курсор: надо сделать сабкласс `UITextField` и в нем переопределить функцию, которая устанавливает размер курсора.

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за информацию! Прочитал третий вариант и он меня натолкнул на мысль: поверх текстФилда добавить `UILabel`, при появлении алертВью достать клавиатуру, и из делегатов `UITextField` менять значение `UILabel`. Как думаете, будет работать?

Comment: тогда уже проще текст филд вынести за экран, тогда и с курсором разбираться не надо :)